# Selecting polygon as Input in QGIS Modeler?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I need to create a model where I select two polygon and the first one is clipped with the second one. Difference function is doing it. But asks for two input layers.

How can I add as Input a Polygon to be selected from canvas?

All the inputs I try ask me for a whole layer and then I can filter by selected features in it.

I have both polygons in the same layer so I click "Only selected features" in both input layers (same input layer in both) and it's not working.

Clipper plugin is not working for me. Maybe because layer is Multipolygon.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `extract by attribute` or `select by attribute` from the available tools? If so, how does the outcome/handling not suit your needs?

Comment: Have you try the plugin "clipper"? https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/clipper/

Comment: @Erik yes, I tried both. Both of them seem to need an Input before executed, Cannot be input for themselves. Although it worked I have to add the filter (atribute='xyz') in the configuration on the step and cannot select a new polygon manually when executing the model

Comment: @Christophe Yes. Plugin gives an error because my layer is Multipolygon and only clips in Polygoin layers...

Comment: I tested with multipolygon : it works. May be your layer have topological error ? Test algorithm "fix" befor clipping.

Comment: @Christophe it's pretty strange. On one pc Splitter is working perfectly. On another pc with same two features (same postgis layer) I am getting this error: TypeError: MultiPolygonZ geometry cannot be converted to a polygon. Only single polygon or curve polygon types are permitted.